# how to know which statement got executed while debugging

Tags: c++, debugging

In my code, sometimes when multiple function calls can be made in a single line. I do not get which function is running right now. 
for example-

```
int foo(){
    if(m==0||n==0) return 0;
    return std::max(foo(a,b,m-1,n),foo(a,b,m,n-1));
}
```

While debugging, understanding which function was called based on all parameters becomes clumsy and sometimes doesn't even work. Is there any option to see processes within a line while debugging. I use codelite IDE.

Comment: What debugger are you using?

Comment: I use codelite.

Comment: Most debuggers offer you to 'step' thru the code, executing commands one by one.

Comment: Yes, I press step into and it jumps into next function call with no indication of which one

Comment: break them out of the return statement and execute each one as code.  ```val1 = foo(a,b,m-1,n); val2 = foo(a,b,m,n-1); return std::max(val1, val2);

Comment: For stuff like this, I just refactor the code to something like `auto first = foo(a,b,m-1,n); auto second = foo(a,b,m,n-1); return std::max(first, second);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are having difficulty debugging code, it usually means you are doing too much in a single line. This means you should split a complex statement into multiple statements. In your case, something like this:

```
int foo(){
    if(m==0||n==0) return 0;
    auto a = foo(a,b,m-1,n);
    auto b = foo(a,b,m,n-1);
    return std::max(a, b);
}
```

Comment: @NathanOliver why do we not know what the types are. foo returns an int.

Comment: That completely answered my question. Just one more thing I want to ask- is there any difference between the flow of this program and the original one.

Comment: @shoelace `foo()` returns an `int`.  From the code provided, we have no idea what `foo(a,b,m-1,n)` returns.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm pretty sure it is safe to declare `int a` and `int b`. Since `std::max(a, b)` must return a type that can be implicitly coerced to an int, then each of `a` and `b` must also be something that can be coerced to an `int`. With that said, `auto` removes the need to reason about this and just let the compiler figure it out.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The problem is `foo(a,b,m-1,n)` could return a long long.  Sure, you can implicitly convert that to an `int`, but if it's value is larger than what an `int` can hold then you've lost all meaning.

Comment: @NathanOliver It has been a while since I have done any serious C++ programming. I'm surprised that it will silently convert a `long long` to an `int` without a compiler error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice A good compiler will warn, but the C++ standard says it's perfectly okay.  You can see it compiling here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ac1d09d649c75d7

Comment: Even with the warnings turned up to max, you wont get a warning from GCC unless you manually specify `-Wconversion`

Comment: @NathanOliver TIL. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives to the current answer could be:

- Stepping into statements. Not likely to work if `foo` calls are inlined
- Debugging disassembly

These alternatives may not work, but if when they work, they allow debugging unaltered code.